# How to shrink all HTML elements when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="sectionOne" class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 80vh;">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" style="color: #0069d9">
    <h1 >Section One</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row section-one-row d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <div style="padding: 40px">
        <div class="card-item" style="padding: 40px;">
            <h3>Card A</h3>
            <h5>
                Some text here. Some text here. Some text here
            </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <div style="padding: 40px">
        <div class="card-item" style="padding: 40px;">
            <h3>Card B</h3>
            <h5>
                Some text here. Some text here. Some text here
            </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <div style="padding: 40px">
        <div class="card-item" style="padding: 40px;">
            <h3>Card C</h3>
            <h5>
              Some text here. Some text here. Some text here
            </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row section-one-row d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button id="caption-button" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which looks like this 
[image]

However, when resizing the browser window the elements in the section look misplaced. How can I prevent this? Or how can I make all elements to resize accordingly when changing the browser window size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There must be some additioanl HTML and CSS I am not seing here. I recreated the page in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/krtcotmo2/pen/MWWrMOw) incliding some additional CSS to get the two to resemble eachother.

```
#sectionOne{
  background: black;
}
#caption-button{
  border-radius:25px;
}
body{
  background:white
}
.card-item{
  background:white
}
```

Even with this I am not able to get the title or button to repostion themselves outside of the container. Which elements are you looking to resize and what is the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing lg in grid class with sm.for ex- col-lg-4 text-center -> col-sm-4 text-center. For more information you can refer bootstrap website(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) under grid option you can find the class names according to size of window/device on which you are running your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I just figured it out and I will post the answer for future reference. On the first `div` component I have `style="height: 80vh;"` which was making the whole section less flexible and less responsive to changes in the browser window size.

I removed `style="height: 80vh;`and now the height of the div readjusts accordingly to fit all elements within that component when changing the size of the window.